# React continuously rendering when calling useEffect dependency

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

In my app, I want to refresh when `matches` is changed. But if I put `matches` in my useEffect dependency array, the page just seems to continuously reload.

code,

```
const [matches, setMatches] = useState();
const loadData =  async() => {
      setPendingApiCall(true);
      await apiCalls
      .getMatches(id)
      .then((response) => {
        setPendingApiCall(false)
        setMatches(response.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setPendingApiCall(false)
        setMatchError('Error loading matches');
        console.log(error)
      })

    }

    useEffect(() => {
      loadData();
    }, [matches])
```

basically when a page loads, it calls my api and get details about matches and sets the `matches` variable to this data which is displayed on the page. The matches data contains scores, when a user updates their score for a match, I am calling the `loadData` func which will return the new data for the `matches`

From my limited understand of react, putting `matches` in the dependency array, should cause the page data to refresh if `matches` changes.

But if I put matches int he dependency array, the page just constantly calls the api. (I've a button which becomes disabled when a pending api call is in progress and the button just keeps flicking between active and disabled)

I have read through the docs and several SO posts, but can't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The issue is that `loadData()` on a successful requests calls `setMatches()` providing it a new object and causes the `useEffect` with dependency array `[matches]` to run again as matches has changed  (comparisons in dependency arrays are reference comparisons, i.e. objects with the exact same values will not match unless they are the same object).

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. So I'd be better not having loadData in the useEffect hook and calling loadData when I expect the data to change such as when updating a score, so that the app gets the data again

Comment: Yes,  a single load on component mount by having an empty dependency array for the `useEffect` and then triggering `loadData` when you know it needs to be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const [matches, setMatches] = useState();
const loadData =  async() => {
      setPendingApiCall(true);
      await apiCalls
      .getMatches(id)
      .then((response) => {
        setPendingApiCall(false)
        setMatches(response.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setPendingApiCall(false)
        setMatchError('Error loading matches');
        console.log(error)
      })

    }

    useEffect(() => {
      loadData();
    }, [])
```

Comment: This just gives an empty dependency array and so page will only load once on initial load and the data wont refresh the `matches` is changed????

Comment: I think you call the function *loadData* manually after you update the matches